como puedo configurar xdebuger para wsl y que funcione con visual studio en windows
estoy intentando correr un xdebuger desde una wsl de ubuntu y en windows se encuentra corriendo el visual estudio con la extensión de xdebuger a la espera de la conexión como puedo configurar el xdebuger para que pueda encontrar la conexión del visual desde la maquina virtual de windows que esta conectada y se encarga de ejecutar el código de php que esta en windows pero esta wsl ejecuta
actualmente ya e probado a configurar el xdebuger de la siguiente manera :
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=172.26.224.1  ; Dirección IP de Windows
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.start_with_request=yes


Te diría que arranques por validar que hay conectividad. ¿Puedes hacer, desde el WSL un ping a 172.26.224.1 y ver que está todo ok? Si eso está bien podrías intentar un telnet a 172.26.224.1 9003 y, luego a ver cómo está la configuración del lado de xdebug
